# IE conditional statements not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have 3 stylesheets, style_ie6.css, style_ie7.css and style.css. Here's what I have:

I've used browserlab, ietester and browsershots and IE6 & 7 are ignoring my conditionals and loading up the main stylesheet.

*edit: don't know why it isn't displaying... here's the live link:http://www.inishrosshouse.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the main stylesheet before the conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for IETester but I this is known behaviour there: When multiple instances of Internet Explorer are installed (or active) on the same system, conditional comments will be resolved against the *highest IE version* available on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what tags you're putting into the ie6 and ie7 versions. First, I'd recommend moving the style.css first. Then only put tags in the ie6 and ie7 that change a tag to make it work in that browser.

Comment: great, it works now. I thought it would work correctly if placed before the main style sheet as the conditional would be read first